# creating a sum function for summing only part of a vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector

Obviously I need a sum function for this and accumulate will not cut it

I need to create program - a vector - with n number of elements the user can prescribe - and the sum function can only sum POSITIVE elements even though the user can enter negative elements as well...

In the computeSum function I also need to add a "success" to the whole group

```
computeSum (dataVec, howMany, total, sucess);
```

and create a parameter for people who enter - all negative numbers but want to sum them but are unable to because there are no positive numbers

```
if (success) {
   cout << "The sum is " << total << endl;
}
else {
cerr << "Oops, you cannot add these elements.";
}
```

So here is what I got

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>        // need this in order to use vectors in the program
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<double> dataVec;

    double i, n, howMany, total;
    cout << "How many numbers would you like to put into the vector?";
    cin >> n; 

    dataVec.resize(n);

    for(vector<double>::size_type i=0;i < n;i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the numbers: \n";
        cin >> dataVec[i];
    }

    cout << "How many POSITIVE numbers would you like to sum?";
    cin >> howMany;
    cout << computeSum (dataVec, howMany, total);
}

 double computeSum (vector<double> &Vec, howMany, total)
 {
      double total =0;
      for(int i=0;i < howMany;i++)
    total+=Vec[i];
      return total;
 }
```

I also seem to having trouble compiling just this - computeSum() is not being understood in int main(); howMany is not being understood in computerSum(); and on a gloabl scope total() and howMany() are undeclared (I guess that would mean i would need to decalre globally???)

Answer (score 3):

In fact, `accumulate` *will* “cut it”, with an appropriate functor that only regards positive values:

```
int sum_positive(int first, int second) {
    return first + (second > 0 ? second : 0);
}

…

std::accumulate(data.begin(), data.begin() + how_many, 0, sum_positive);
```

Comment: I think, the overload which you want to use takes `4` arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Getting on my hobby horse: Boost Range Adaptors. Hits the sweet point with me

```
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/numeric.hpp>

bool isnatural(int i) { return i>=0; }
using namespace boost::adaptors;

int main(int argc, char** args)
{
    static const int data[] = { -130, -1543, 4018, 5542, -4389, 15266, };

    std::cout << "sum: " << boost::accumulate(data | filtered(isnatural), 0) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> sum: 24826

---

With C++11 <strike>awesomeness</strike><sup>1</sup> *spice*:

```
std::cout << "sum: " << boost::accumulate(data 
        | filtered([] (int i) { return i>=0; }), 0) << std::endl;
```

> <sup>1</sup>: to be honest, I really hate the clumsyness of lambda syntax:
>
> - having to specify the parameter type *always*
> - having to spell out the return statement to 
>     For this scenario, it seems to that 
>   `filtered([] (i) { i>=0 })`
>     could be figured out by the compiler. Well, perhaps in c++22 :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `computeSum()` function must appear above your `main()` function in the source file for it to be in scope. Also in your `computeSum()` function signature you haven't given types to the `howMany` and `total` variables. I'm guessing they should be `double howMany` and `double total`?

Comment: "*Your `computeSum()` function must appear above your main() function in the source file for it to be in scope.*" -- Not true. What is true is that either the definition or a declaration of `computeSum()` needs to appear before `main()`.