# Boolean and Void problem

Tags: c++

So here is my code a little more edited however now I'm stuck on the success parameter:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>        // need this in order to use vectors in the program
using namespace std;

void computeSum (vector<int> &Vec, int  howMany, int total, bool success) 
//the computeSum function that will sum positive numbers in a vector
{
success = true;
total=0;
if (success){
for(int j=0;j < howMany;j++)
    if (Vec[j] > 0){
    total+=Vec[j];
    } else { 
    total+=Vec[j+1];
    }
return total;
} else {
cerr << "Oops!  Appears you cannot add up these numbers!";
}

}

int main()
{
vector<int> dataVec;

int i, n, howMany, total;
cout << "How many numbers would you like to put into the vector? \n";
cin >> n; 

dataVec.resize(n);

for(vector<int>::size_type i=0;i < n;i++)
{
    cout << "Enter your number for " << i+1 << ": \n"; 
    cin >> dataVec[i];
}

cout << "How many POSITIVE numbers would you like to sum? \n";
cin >> howMany;
cout << "Your total is: \n" << computeSum (dataVec, howMany, total, success);
}
```

When I compile it I get errors like this:
- return statement with a value in function returning void - so in that case would my "return total" in the if statement just print out the total?
- In also says in the int main() function that success was not declared - how would i go about declaring it?

Comment: You are attempting something beyond your ability. Start with "Hello World" and work up.

Comment: Incidentally, you also declare `main` to have an `int` result, yet you never return anything.  I suspect the compiler will gripe about that as well.

Comment: @Daniel: Not in C++ (or C99).  Falling off the end of `main` does an implicit `return 0;`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [creating a sum function for summing only part of a vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463310/creating-a-sum-function-for-summing-only-part-of-a-vector)

Answer (score 3):

A `void` return value means the function doesn't return anything. If you want to return `total`, an `int`, the return type should be `int`.

And, yes, you need to declare variables before you use them. Your `main` function has no `success` variable declared and, in fact, it appears to be totally unnecessary anyway.

I'd consider removing `success` totally from your code, not passing `total` to the function (it's unnecessary if you're going to return it), and getting rid of the passed-in `howMany` - vectors in C++ have a `size` method which gives you the size of the vector and you can use that within the function.

And, one more thing, the construct:

```
for(int j=0;j < howMany;j++)
    if (Vec[j] > 0){
        total+=Vec[j];
    } else { 
        total+=Vec[j+1];
    }
```

is not going to behave itself. In cases where an element is not positive, it will add the *next* element, double counting, and irrespective of its sign.

You probably need something like (pseudocode):

```
for each index:
    if vector[index] > 0:
        add vector[index] to total
```

This will give you the sum of all positive values, ignoring the negatives totally.

Answer (score 1):

You've got `return total` in a function that returns `void`.  `void` means that the function returns nothing.

Methinks you expect `return total` to update the `total` parameter in your call, but that's not the way it works.

Better go back to square one and read about value parameters and function results.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all, you are trying to return a bool from a function with return type void. Change the return type to void.

About declaring success, simply declare it like every other variable you have declared.